# Haskell error Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [c]

Tags: haskell

When i try to load my code using ghci it gives me this error:

```
Asig1.hs:4:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [c]
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘f’ has the inferred type
      f :: forall c (t :: * -> *).
           (Num c, Num [c], Foldable t) =>
           [c] -> [c] -> t [c] -> ([c], [c])
```

I don't understand what i did wrong.
This is my code:

```
module Asig1 where

f as ys x = (s,z)
       where
       ws = zipWith (*) as ys
       s = foldl (+) ws x
       z = s
```

Comment: if you add a type signature to `f` (maybe `[Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> (Int, Int)`) then you'll help the compiler understand which part of your program is wrong, and you'll probably get a more helpful error.

Answer (score 7):

Because you use [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldl) probably the wrong way. `foldl` has as signature:

```
Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

So you feed it a function (here `(+)`) an initial value and a sequence of values. You can probably fix your code with:

```
module Asig1 where

f as ys x = (s,z)
       where
       ws = zipWith (*) as ys
       s = foldl (+) x ws --instead of foldl (+) ws x
       z = s
```

You can further improve your code because `z = s` is not necessary:

```
module Asig1 where

f as ys x = (s,s)
       where
       ws = zipWith (*) as ys
       s = foldl (+) x ws --instead of foldl (+) ws x
```